# Alternative to Windows Credential Provider

Tags: .net, windows

I'm not interested in replacing the window login.  I want to display a message to the user after they have successfully logged in.  But I want to force them to hit the OK button before they can continue using the system.  Users in the past have claimed to not have seen the message.  Therefore, I want to force user interaction or "confirmation".

Comment: I found another interesting solution.  I created a new desktop and displayed my form in the new desktop.  Once the user clicked, ok, the desktop is removed and the original desktop is displayed.  it doesn't prevent anyone from using ctrl-alt-del and stopping the proces.  I'm still looking at the other 2 answers.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to show some text (typically [Legal Notice](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc939716.aspx)) **before** user logs on. This can be pushed by [group policy (described here)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc779661(v=WS.10).aspx). Perhaps you can (mis)use it for your purpose.

Answer (score 0):

There is no out of the box solution for this. And there is no easy way to fully enforce user confirmation prior to using the system. Some problems are:

1. Your program might not be set on autostart (or be removed from autostart by the user)
2. The user might always hit ctrl-alt-del to bring up the task manager (and perhaps even kill your application).
3. Your software might be loaded after some other software has been loaded already.

If it's for a system with limited access for the user (for instance a public terminal) and if you can also configure windows properly to work with your software, you could get around these problems eventually, but for end user systems I don't think you can.